# Error al ejecutar el programa 'npm.cmd': Acceso denegado

Tags: nodejs

tengo una api en nodeJS el cual estoy intentando ejecutar cualquier comando en la terminal me sale este error

```
Error al ejecutar el programa 'npm.cmd': Acceso denegado. En línea: 1 Carácter: 1      
+ npm start
+ ~~~~~~~~~.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ npm start
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Al ejecutar el archivo index.js me rechaza la conexión en el google chrome y retorna el siguiente error

(index):6774 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

He intentado cambiar el puerto del launch.json y borrando también el archivo pero sin éxito.

Comment: que sistema operativo tienes? dentro del proyecto tienes algun archivo llamado `npm.cmd`?

Comment: Windows 10, no tengo ningún archivo llamado así

Comment: En realidad cualquier comando que ejecute desde la terminal me sale ese error

Comment: Revisa si tienes permisos para acceder a la consola de comandos (cmd), puede ser que algun virus u otro problema haya afectado a tu equipo y este bloqueara el acceso a la consola.

Comment: Si estas utilizando PowerShell Utiliza cmd como administrador y podras ejecutar los comandos de npm aunque eso no resulve el problema, lo mas sensillo es volver a instalar node